# Capturing all fired Intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent, intentfilter

Whenever User click anywhere on mobile screen some intent is fired either Third part app or system intent, so is it possible to make a receiver which can show me which intent has been fired. What will be IntentFilter to achieve it. Can some one guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever User click anywhere on mobile screen some intent is fired

That is incorrect.

> is it possible to make a receiver which can show me which intent has been fired

Fortunately, no. Developers cannot spy on the entire `Intent`-based communication system, for obvious privacy and security reasons. As usual, there may be possibilities for this sort of spyware on rooted devices.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are looking for. But if you want to find the source of the Intent you can do the following.

Let's say you have two activities A & B. Have Activity A invoke/call Activity B via startActivityForResult(). Then in Activity B you can use getCallingActivity.getClassName() to retrieve the source intent.